# Adding list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I have lists `D` and `E`. I am adding element of `E` to each element of `D`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
D=[[0],[1]]
E=[[4]]
G=[]
for i in range(0,len(D)): 
    for j in range(0,len(E)): 
        F=D[i]+E[j]
        G.append(F) 
print(G)
```

The current output is

```
[[0, 4], [1, 4]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 4], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D=[[0],[1]]
E=[[4]]
G = []
for item in D:
    for item_ in E:
        F = [item[0], item[0] + item_[0]]
        G.append(F)
print(G)
```

or by using itertools:

```
import itertools
D=[[0],[1]]
E=[[4]]
G=[]
for item, item_ in itertools.product(D, E):
    F = [item[0], item[0] + item_[0]]
    G.append(F)
print(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
D=[[0],[1]]
E=[[4]]
G=[]
for i in range(0,len(D)): 
    for j in range(0,len(E)): 
        F=[D[i][0], D[i][0]+E[j][0]]
        G.append(F) 
print(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach for even longer lists:

```
   D=[[0],[1]]
   E=[[4],[5]]
   G=[]
   for i in range(len(D)): 
       for j in E:
           for a in j:
               G.append(D[i]+[a+i])
    print(G)
```

This results in a list of all possible combinations between the elements of D and E. The code uses the length of the lists D and E to determine the number of iterations, so it can handle lists of any length without needing to modify the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @xlmaster what do you think now?